# Do not repeat acknowledged events after reconnect to persistent connection in EventStore

Tags: node.js, eventstoredb

I'm using Eventstore `20.6.1.0`
And this client https://github.com/EventStore/EventStore-Client-NodeJS
When I publish events to eventstore and acknowledge them in subscriber like this

```
      const onEvent = 
        (event: ResolvedEvent, report: PersistentReport) => {
          if (event.event) {
            report.ack(event.event.id);
          }
        }
```

If I disconnect from eventstore and reconnect again I receive all acknowledged events again

Why I receive acknowledged events, but not only new?

Comment: I've just tested this and it seems to work. Are you sure the events are being correctly acknowledged. What happens when you add an error handler `.on("error", (e: Error) => { console.log(e.message); })` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create persistent connection you have to set max checkpoint count.
In my case I've sent less events than `maxCheckpointCount` and they were not acknowledged before disconnect. That's why after reconnect I received them again.

```
    await createPersistentSubscription(streamName, groupName)
      .fromStart()
      .enableLinkResolution()
      .consumerStrategy(ROUND_ROBIN)
      .maxCheckpointCount(1)
      .minCheckpointCount(1)
      .execute(connection)
```